# How do I add an image in the drawable folder to an ImageView in Android Studio 1.2?

Tags: android, image, imageview, drawable

Since Google added the mipmap folder for the launcher icons, I have had issues using the drawables folder. I manually added the hdpi folders in the drawable folder, but when I try and add the src path, the images won't allow me to view and select them. How do I add an image in the drawable folder to an ImageView in Android Studio 1.2?

Comment: restart android eclipse or cleanup project and then try my code answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this way of code there are three ways to set image on ImageView

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
```

or

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProfileBg"
            android:src="@drawable/image_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

or

```
              <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/ivProfileBg"
              android:background="@drawable/image_name"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste the PNG image in the following directory `<Project-Name>\app\src\main\res\drawable\`
(if the drawable directory doesn't exist, create a new one).

now add the src attribute to the imageView like i done.

```
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfileBg"

                android:src="@drawable/image_name"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

where the image_name is the name of the PNG image you just pasted into the drawable directory.

if you wanted to paste the image into the hdpi section, you must create the directory under `res\` folder, then the path would be `<Project-Name>\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\`

Comment: It gives me an error saying that it `Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/main_title`

Answer (score 0):

Top left of the screen, right below the Project name, there's a project overview (directories, files etc.) change it from 'Android' to 'Project'. then go to /app/src/main/res. then right click on res and create a drawable folder inside! Put your thing there. you can access the resource using:
@drawable/... inside whenever you're going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding hdpi folder inside of the drawable folder will not work, because it will not be discovered by android. For easier navigation you can switch and view of Project Explorer from '**Android**' to '**Project**' like below:

[image]

In project view you can explore all the drawable folders including hdpi, mdpi etc like the following path src **app/src/main/res/...**

[image]:

Comment: I already have the folders, but I cannot access what is within them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to **not** make the drawable hdpi folders subfolders. Android Studio then automatically categorizes them under the drawable folder. Thanks for all of your help!