# Where need I put images?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native project to create ios/android app;
I don't know Where is images location?
Where to put all images? like background-image and else.
Is I need to use two diffrents folders? to ios and android?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: yes I did it but not get any answer!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154989/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-drawable-folder-to-an-imageview-in-android-studio-1

Comment: "android imageview example " type on google you will get lot of tutorials with example

Comment: yes I know but I don't know if there is a difference between java android project and react-native project.... do you know about it?

Comment: look on my question tags, and your question tags are not the same!...

Comment: sorry I cant I dont know how its created- a chat order...

Comment: My question is about the location - whitch folder... not how to get the image...

Comment: After searching... Get some link added  in answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching... Get this link:

[React Native local images with URI on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660195/react-native-local-images-with-uri-on-android)
very helpful link!! Thank you! –

There they talking about the place of images for android, in react native project.